# Should microservices use only nosql databases?

Tags: nosql, microservices

I'm new to microservices, but the more I research ,the more I conclude that a microservice is basically a sql table in a monolithic app (perhaps oversimplified) . For example , instead of having a monolithic e commerce app, you would have a users microservice, a products microservice, orders etc. And this would bring along a lot of data redundancy with it seeing how each microservice has its own database.

So my question would be, considering all this, is it logical for each microservice to use only nosql databases instead of rdbms ? If not, can you give an example of a good reason for a microservice to use an sql db over nosql?

Comment: Those seem to be completely orthogonal issues. Also NoSQL is quite a broad term that covers a wide range of very different systems and it is hard to recommend a proper database product based on just "NoSQL vs RDBMS" (and without any information on actual application requirements, too).

Comment: "a microservice is basically a sql table in a monolithic app (perhaps oversimplified)". Perhaps...  Why wouldn't your order service have multiple tables (orders, line items, billing addresses, shipping addresses) for example?

Comment: Those sound more like columns rather than seperate tables, and they could just aswell be keys of a mongodb collection for instance? Isn't the whole point of rdbms avoiding data redundancy, which seems to be unavoidable with microservices?

Comment: rdbms is not just about data normalisation, and that is not just about avoiding redundancy, it is also about transactions, durability, joins, a powerful and standard query language, schemas, triggers, stored procedures, mature tooling etc.

Comment: I am not saying RDBMS is better suited for your application than NoSQL. I am saying any such recommendation depends only on the specific application and has nothing to do with microservice vs monolith or what programming language you use or if it is self-hosted or in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are reasons for microservices to be built on top of nosql databases instead of relational databases.

The only reason to choose one or the other depends upon your requirements and the model necessary for your solution.

We are switching to microservices, but our solution is for administrative work, which is much easier done with a RDBMS than with an ad-hoc nosql system.